# Computer won't boot if I connect an externally powered USB hub to it when the PC is powered off

Tags: boot, usb, bios

As the title suggests, today I ran into a rather unusual problem: If I connect an externally powered USB hub with the computer turned off, the power button stops working despite the fact that the PC is properly powered. While if I connect it after switching on, no problem occurs.

I currently have an ASUS B75M-A motherboard with BIOS version 0801 mounted in the computer.

Why is this happening? Are there any settings in the BIOS that need to be changed to correct this?

Comment: See what the BIOS boot sequence is, and lower the USB to a lower setting in the sequence.  This assumes that does not put disk drive at the top as that may fail and prevent starting. I had that type of problem at a customer some years back - not recently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have updated the application and, having not connected any USB device to the HUB, I cannot change the boot priorities.

Comment: Your only solution then, is to disconnect the HIUB before starting. That is a HUB / BIOS incompatibility.

Comment: @Pinguto Just for reference, the stuff over here beneath a main post are known as comments. This is where users ask or discuss more details or provide you with some ideas that *might* end up being an answer, but is in that “in between” period where community members are trying to better understand what this situation is all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that power button stops working strongly suggests that your hub has a strong voltage back driving into your mainboard, which breaks power-up sequence on system embedded controller. This frequently occurs with cheap uncertified hubs, the hub is faulty.

Try to disconnect external power to your hub and try to reboot. Worse, this kind of backdriving might cause complete BIOS lockup, so total BIOS clean-up will be needed (total removing of CMOS battery and holding the CMOS rail shorted to ground for several seconds)